# Compare two files and remove the common lines

Tags: python

I have two  files. File1 with data

```
DF2SVT-(.CD(),.CP(clk),.D(),.SDN(),.Q(na));

OAI3DSVT-(.A1(na),.A2(),.A3(),.B(),.ZN(y));

GLHSVT-(.D(v),.E(),.Q(y));

DCCDSVT-(.I(w),.ZN(y));
```

and file2 with data

```
GLHSVT-(.D(v),.E(),.Q(y));
```

If the line in file2 is present in file1 then remove that line from file1 and print rest of the lines of file1.
So I want output file fout as

```
DF2SVT-(.CD(),.CP(clk),.D(),.SDN(),.Q(na));

OAI3DSVT-(.A1(na),.A2(),.A3(),.B(),.ZN(y));

DCCDSVT-(.I(w),.ZN(y));
```

I know how to print common lines between two files using

```
for line in file1 & file2:
    if line:
       print line
```

But I am not getting how to remove that common line from file if match is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the lines of both files into a separate variables. Iterate over the lines of the first file, and for each of one them check if they exist on the second file, if not then save them into the first file.

```
with open(file1, "r") as file1:
     lines_file1 = file1.readlines()
with open(file, "r") as file2:
     lines_file2 = file2.readlines()
     with open(file1, "w") as f_w:
           for line in lines_file1:
               if line not in lines_file2
                  f_w.write(line)
```

The downside of this approach is that you are loading the entire files into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **set operations** to do this with few lines of code.

Read two file and convert the list of lines into the set and use set operations

```
line_file1 = set(line_file1)
line_file2 = set(line_file2)
result = line_file1 - line_file2
```

Now write the **result** set each element (line) to the file.

**Note**: repeated data in file1 will be also removed.